# Title is not showing for second image in slider

Tags: javascript, php, html

In my Slider, every slide has different animation some have come from the top, some from the bottom and so on.I want the image to come from the database with different animations.
The code will display all image in the table.

> title- title of image
>   position - which position image show (1 to 5)
>   image_path - show image path which is store in UploadImage.
>   Title for second slider is not showing.

```
<?php 
include_once('connection.php');
$query1="SELECT * FROM slider";
$result1=mysqli_query($conn,$query1);
?>
```

And my slider code id:
How could I display images with different animations

```
 <ul> 
 <?php  $i=1;
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_object($result1))
        {echo $row->position; 
    ?>
    <li data-index="1" data-slotamount="7" data-easein="Power4.easeInOut" data-easeout="Power4.easeInOut" data-masterspeed="600" data-rotate="0" data-saveperformance="off">
        <!-- MAIN IMAGE -->
        <img src="<?php echo "admin/UploadImage/".$row->image_path; ?>"  alt=""  data-bgposition="center center" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat" data-bgparallax="10" class="rev-slidebg" data-no-retina>
        <!-- LAYERS -->
        <div class="tp-caption first_text" 
            data-width="none"
            data-height="none"
            data-whitespace="nowrap"
            data-voffset="['260']"
            data-hoffset="['40','120','40']"
            data-x="left" 
            data-y="top"
            data-fontsize="['48']" 
            data-lineheight="['55']" 
            data-transform_idle="o:1;"
            data-frames='[{"from":"x:[-100%];z:0;rX:0deg;rY:0;rZ:0;sX:1;sY:1;skX:0;skY:0;","mask":"x:0px;y:0px;s:inherit;e:inherit;","speed":1500,"to":"o:1;","delay":500,"ease":"Power3.easeInOut"},{"delay":"wait","speed":1000,"to":"x:[-100%];","mask":"x:inherit;y:inherit;s:inherit;e:inherit;","ease":"Power3.easeInOut"}]'
            data-textAlign="['left','left','left','left']"
            data-paddingtop="[0,0,0,0]"
            data-paddingright="[0,0,0,0]"
            data-paddingbottom="[0,0,0,0]"
            data-paddingleft="[0,0,0,0]"
            data-start="800" 
            data-splitin="none" 
            data-splitout="none" 
            data-responsive_offset="on"> <?php echo $row->title; ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="tp-caption download_btn"
            data-whitespace="nowrap"
            data-voffset="['390']"
            data-hoffset="['40','120','40']"
            data-x="left"
            data-transform_idle="o:1;"
            data-transform_in="y:[100%];z:0;rX:0deg;rY:0;rZ:0;sX:1;sY:1;skX:0;skY:0;opacity:0;s:2000;e:Power4.easeInOut;" 
            data-transform_out="y:[100%];s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;" 
            data-mask_in="x:0px;y:[100%];s:inherit;e:inherit;" 
            data-mask_out="x:inherit;y:inherit;s:inherit;e:inherit;"  
            data-y="top"
            data-start="1800" >
            <a class="register_angkar_btn" href="#">Registration</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <?php $i++; }?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem by add this code in `li` `tag` :

```
 data-index="<?php echo $row->position;?>"
```